# I want to fetch data from 2 different table

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch result `master.category` wise suppose if i have

```
$category ='doctor'
```

then how can i get the result? i have drawn the tables below and expected result also, Please help me. thanks

```html
table name->Master
------------------

id        label        category

1       expertise       doctor
2          fee          doctor
3       appontment      doctor
4       services        lawyer
5       qualification   student





table name->Field
------------------

id       label_id      Information
1           1           desntist
2           1           general_physician
3           1           general_surgeons
4           4           criminal_law
5           5           civil_law



expected result               
--------------------
 expertise       

dentist
general_physician
general_surgeons
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a `JOIN` like

```
select f.information as 'expertise'
from field f
join  master m on m.id = f.label_id
where m.category = 'doctor';
```

Answer (score 0):

its query give all information by master's id

```
SELECT m.label, GROUP_CONCAT(Information) 
FROM Master m
JOIN Field f 
ON m.id = f.label_id
WHERE m.category = 'doctor'
```